# Загрузка первой половины страницы быстрее второй

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт.
Который скрывает все содержимое страницы до полной загрузки документа, вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы "background1" загружался не ожидая загрузки "background2" и остального содержимого страницы, но только после полной загрузки самого себя.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var div4 = document.querySelector('.hide4');

  div4 && div4.classList.remove('hide4')

  var div5 = document.querySelector('.hide5');

  div5 && div5.classList.remove('hide5')

};
```

```css
.hide4 {
  display: none;
}

.hode5 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide4">
  <div class="background1">
    ..content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hide5">
  <div class="background2">
    ..content2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну так display:none; убери и все.

Comment: откуда убрать ? по подробнее если можно

Comment: если убрать display:none; с background1 то он будет загружаться "находу" а не после полной загрузки , мне нужно как и описал выше , чтобы background1 загружался после полной загрузки самого себя